# PHP array parsing error

Tags: php

I have just got a PHP project, but I get a lot of array parsing errors. The arrays in question are following:

```
function patch($url, array $options = [])
{
    return request('PATCH', $url, $options);
}
```

and

```
    $options = RequestEvents::convertEventArray(
        $options,
        ['complete', 'error'],
        [
            'priority' => RequestEvents::EARLY,
            'once' => true,
            'fn' => function ($e) use ($hash) {
                $hash[$e->getRequest()] = $e;
            }
        ]
    );
```

In both of them the parser compalins about unexpected "[". The version of PHP running at server is 5.3.28, which as far as I know, supports this array structure.

What could be possibly wrong here?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Either update your PHP to 5.4, or convert [..] to array(...)

Comment: The `[]` shortcut syntax was introduced in 5.4!

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.3 doesnot support short syntax for array, you need to update to [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) or change your syntax to [array()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)